# xsl to php array

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I got a xml file that contains hierarchical data. Now I need to get some of that data into a php array. I use xsl to get the data I want formatted as a php array. But when I print it it leaves all the tabs and extra spaces and line breaks etc which I need to get rid of to turn it into a flat string (I suppose!) and then convert that string into a array.

In the xsl I output as text and have indent="no" (which does nothing). I've tried to strip \t \n \r etc but it doesn't affect the output at all.

Is there a really good php function out there that can strip out all formatting except single spaces? Or is there more going on here I don't know about or another way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

First off, using xsl output to form your PHP array is fairly inelegant and inefficient.  I would highly suggest going with something like the domdocument class available in PHP (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).  If you must stick with your current method, try using regular expressions to remove any unnecessary whitespace.

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

or

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string);
```

to preserve single white space.

Comment: +1 for using explicit XML library functions instead of xsl for this. Besides the mentioned DOMDocument class, you might want to check http://de2.php.net/simplexml as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I've created [a class for opensource library](http://code.google.com/p/blibrary/source/browse/trunk/classes/bXml.class.inc) that your welcome to use, and look at as an example on how to create an array from XML (and just take out the "good" parts).

**USING XML**

So the crux of the problem is probably keeping the data in XML as long as possible. Therefore the **after** the XSL translation you would have something like:

```
<xml>
    <data>value 
          with newline
    </data>
    <data>with      lots    of    whitespace</data>
</xml>
```

Then you could loop trough that data like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
foreach($xml as $data)
{
    // use str_replace or a regular expression to replace the values...
    $data_array[] = str_replace(array("  ", "\n"), "", $data);
}

// $data_array is the array you want!
```

**USING JSON**

However if you can't output the XSL into XML then loop through it. Then you may want to use XSL to create a JSON string object and convert that to an array so the xsl would look like:

```
{
    "0" : "value 
           with newline",
    "1" : "with      lots    of    whitespace"
}
```

Then you could loop trough that data like:

```
$json_array = json_encode($json_string, TRUE); // the TRUE is to make an array
foreach($json_array as $key => $value)
{ 
    // use str_replace or a regular expression to replace the values...
    $json_array[$key] = str_replace(array("  ", "\n"), "", $value);
}
```

Either way you'll have to pull the values in PHP because XSLT's handling of spaces and newlines is pretty rudimentary.